# Problem getting real-time_map using hector_slam!

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, pointcloud-to-laserscan, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

'Hello all,

I am using Xbox360, Ros Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04LTS

I am new to ROS. I want to map an unknown enviroment using kinect. For this I am using freenect and gmapping.
I have done these steps:

1. roslaunch freenect_launch  freenect.launch
2. rosrun pointcloud_to_laserscan pointcloud_to_laserscan_node cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points
3. rosbag record -O mybag /scan
4. rostopic echo /scan          /////////i can see scan data is available here
5. rqt_graph

here is my [MY RQT_GRAPH](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P10v22SWJYPIo_2HziGoaON2TSl-oPYk) and here is [MY FRAMES.PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wubudBvtFN2D0_AEz6lsZAdQK5L8GlLA)

This is all great.

But the problem is getting data from the bag file

1. roscore
2. rosparam set use_sim_time true
3. roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch scan:=/base_scan
4. rosbag play --clock mybag.bag
5. rqt_graph

here is my [MY RQT_GRAPH](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kipWQA95MoOC9qUFm06J336YTk2kBlQa) and here is [MY FRAMES.PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XqM7RxhbN8QMM6QS84NU7Nu2MqCFDoPv)

I can't see any error in RViz. But I can't see the map either.
The terminal where I launch hector_slam shows the error that

```
[ WARN] [1515990267.492285826]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.002855 seconds of waiting. This warning only prints once.
[ INFO] [1515990270.173023564]: lookupTransform base_footprint to camera_depth_optical_frame timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
```

5. rostopic pub syscommand std_msgs/String "savegeotiff"

but the terminal in which tutorial.launch is running stated that

```
[ INFO] [1515995399.174200553]: HectorSM sysMsgCallback, msg contents: savegeotiff 
[ INFO] [1515995399.174327483]: HectorSM Map service called
[ INFO] [1515995399.194847114]: GeotiffNode: Map service called successfully
[ INFO] [1515995399.222169236]: Cannot determine map extends!
[ INFO] [1515995399.222222911]: Couldn't set map transform
```

I HAVE ALSO RUN `rosrun tf view_frames` AND I NOTICED THAT `world`  IS NOT CONNECTED TO `base_frame`

can anyone help me  with   this

please do post a comment if any other specifications required.

Thank you in advance.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279764/problem-getting-real-time_map-using-hector_slam!!!/) by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-14**:\

> Lookuptransform Data _______cannot publish transform...............or something like........... no connection between base_frame

I highly doubt that this is the actual error that you're getting. Please update your question with a copy and paste of the *actual* error message from the terminal.

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-14**:
I have updated my question.@jayess

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-16**:
@NAGALLA DEEPAK: is your `caps lock` and/or `/` key broken?

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-18**:
Thank you @gvdhoorn for all the struggle you have taken to edit my question. There isn't any problem with my keys but I  have typed like that only to highlight important  things.

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-18**:
Could some one give solution  to my question?
It is very urgent.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-18**:
@NAGALLA DEEPAK we all have deadlines. It's not like people aren't answering because they don't *want* to. Perhaps no one who has seen your question has time to answer it (giving good answers takes a lot of time) or knows the solution. http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Etiquette

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-18**:
I haven't used `hextor_slam` but it looks like you have a problem with your network. Are you using a simulator or a physical robot?

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-19**:
Sorry for the earlier post.

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-19**:
I only have a kinect and no robot. I have read that hector slam does not transform data

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2018-01-26**:
Try this command----       rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_frame world

**Comment by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) on 2018-01-26**:
I have tried the command and got this https://drive.google.com/open?id=188nGPpFR-59_4Bd7rHJo_NNa2cSJCRSk yes there is some change in the frames. But a **new frame** **1** is being added to the frames.pdf but I think base_frame should be connected to world and not to the "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

After going through different tutorials, and through the help of some people, I am able to produce the map.

For this I have established the TF between different frames manually.

By this command

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 nav base_footprint 100
```

in the terminal.

Also used the above line to connect ( base_footprint and base_frame) also ( laser and camera_link ).

This way I am able to produce the real time map.

Thanks to all who has helped me in getting this work done.

---

Originally posted by [NAGALLA DEEPAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/33107/nagalla-deepak/) with karma: 18 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0